# Need a help to get data to other table

Tags: java, mysql, database

i have two table name resister and user
**register Table have**
id  name surname email username password

**user table have**

```
user_id username password reg_id(fk)
```

i want to get register table username and password  data to user table

i write query like
`"SELECT Username ,Password FROM register  INNER JOIN  user ON  Id=reg_id"`

but i get

> **Error :** com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'Username' in field list is ambiguous

need a help ?
thankyou

Comment: Clearly both tables have username column. So qualify the selected column with table name or its alias

Comment: `SELECT register.Username ,Password FROM register  INNER JOIN  user ON  Id=reg_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because of both tables has Username column .. You need to specify from which table you would like to get data in projection

Try this

Select register.Username, register.Password from register INNER JOIN user on register.Id=user.reg_id

Comment: Thank you  Khayyam Sadigov and Aaqib